# Why are the installed linux header files empty?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, kernel

I'm running 14.04, installed onto an empty hard drive.  The Linux header files are installed, but the `.h` files are empty.  I can see the files here are all zero length:  `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-37-generic/include/config` .

The header files are installed as per:

```
> sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-3.13.0-37-generic is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
```

How can I *really* install the header files, such that they have a non-zero length?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting? If you want the full kernel source, it's in `linux-source`.

Comment: Two questions really.  1) Why are the files empty?  2) How can I get just the header files without installing linux-source?

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r)`?

Comment: Didn't work.  I also looked at the file:  /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.13.0-37-generic_3.13.0-37.64_amd64.deb and did a manual unpack and the files were empty as a result.  Manual unpack was with:  dpkg-deb -x *.deb /tmp/extract/

Comment: @Jeff, you have given a bounty to lemonsqueeze for his answer, if that what you where looking for please accept his answer. see https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just came across [this](http://www.spinics.net/lists/newbies/msg36452.html), according to Kristof:

> include/config is not used for header files at all. It's part of a 
>   clever trick to optimize the kernel build.
>
> The kernel configuration (stored in .config) is used to generate a
>   header file which is used throughout the kernel. 
>   The problem is that changing one option means all files which include
>   config.h will need to be rebuilt, even though most of them may not be
>   affected by that option.
>
> This is solved by removing the makefile dependency on config.h and
>   replacing it by a dependency on one of the files in include/config.
>   Each file there corresponds to a configuration option. Whenever that
>   option is changed the configuration system touches that file (updating
>   its timestamp causing make to rebuild all dependant files.

Comment: Some more information: http://www.spinics.net/lists/newbies/msg36452.html

Comment: thank you for this! I was wondering why I had empty header files there in my kernel build.